# Android RecyclerView with custom item and each item show progress bar to load data asynchronously

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, progress-bar

I need to implement RecylerView with 6 items and these 6 item needs to call separate APIs to load data and I need to show progress bar on each item while making api calls asynchronously and whoever will get the data first will show data on tile and will dismiss his progressbar. Others will continue with progressbar till the time they'll fetch the data. Can anyone suggest best approach to do this.

Comment: why would you want to use recycler view if there is just 6 items?

Comment: bcause they can increase in future.

Comment: Is there anything that I can do with Recyclerview-Itemanimator??

Answer (score 0):

The standard approach would be,

1. Add `ProgressBar` element to your RecyclerView item view.
2. Add a flag `inProgress` (boolean) in your data that you use to populate the RecyclerView Adapter.
3. Use this flag to show/hide the progress in your item.
4. When data is downloaded, update the list of items in your adapter and change `inProgress` to false for that item (add more details if you wish).
5. Call `adapter.notifyItemChanged(position)` to render that item only.

Comment: I'm using recyclerview with multiple views to render different 2 tiles so when I'll call APIs to get the List of data for adapter till then loading spinner should show on each row/tile(6 different rows with different layout). so will it be a good approach to do it as you said.

Comment: This approach will work. But I can not comment on the user experience.